# Why Gitlab CI docker build tagging problem

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have been trying to build my project and deployment to a remote server using gitlab CI runner and using this link as reference
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-continuous-deployment-pipeline-with-gitlab-ci-cd-on-ubuntu-18-04

After runing the pipeline, the publish stage is giving error about the docker tagging

```
$ docker build -t $TAG_COMMIT -t $TAG_LATEST .
invalid argument "/patch-9:64a25b49" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format
```

I have tried changing the docker build tagging in different formats but still could not find out why the error.
I have tried changing the tagging

```
TAG_LATEST: ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}:latest
TAG_COMMIT:${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}:${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}
```

but I am still get the error

```
$ cd $GOPATH/src/$REPO/$NAMESPACE/$PROJECT
$ docker build -t $TAG_COMMIT -t $TAG_LATEST .
invalid argument "/patch-10:fbf4855b" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format
See 'docker build --help'.
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` file looks

```yaml
image: golang:1.15.3

variables:
  REPO: github.com
  NAMESPACE: daniel
  PROJECT: danapp
  TAG_LATEST: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:latest
  TAG_COMMIT: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA

before_script:
  - mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/$REPO/$NAMESPACE/$PROJECT
  - cp -r -v $CI_PROJECT_DIR $GOPATH/src/github.com/daniel
  - cd $GOPATH/src/$REPO/$NAMESPACE/$PROJECT

stages:
  - build
  - publish
  - deploy

compile:
  stage: build
  script:
    - go build -race -ldflags "-extldflags '-static'" -o $CI_PROJECT_DIR/danapp
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - danapp

publish:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: publish
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker build -t $TAG_COMMIT -t $TAG_LATEST .
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker push $TAG_COMMIT
    - docker push $TAG_LATEST

deploy:
  image: alpine:latest
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - deployment
  before_script:
    - apk update && apk add openssh-client
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  
  script:
    - chmod og= $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
    - apk update && apk add openssh-client
    - ssh -i $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@192.168.x.x "docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY"
    - ssh -i $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@192.168.x.x  "docker pull $TAG_COMMIT"
    - ssh -i $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@192.168.x.x  "docker container rm -f danapp || true"
    - ssh -i $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@192.168.x.x  "docker run -d -p 20005:20005 --name danapp $TAG_COMMIT"
  
  environment: stagging
  only:
    - master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you change your `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` to `$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG`
Maybe this solved.
[image]

Comment: This helped me. My `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` contained a `/` symbol and it it was breaking `docker build -t "... $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME ..."`, after change to `$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG` it worked.